# Bitmap download for numerous images causing issue

Tags: android, bitmap

I am learning Android dev. and am developping a [Hearthstone](http://eu.battle.net/hearthstone/en/) app using a [Hearthstone API](http://hearthstoneapi.com/) for fun.

My users can search for specific cards and now I wish to implement a `Card Displayer` that displays cards by their type, and lets the user swipe right or left to display the next one in my `JSONArray`. My API request gives me one and each `JSONObject` has an `img` attribute with the cards image `URL`.

Therefore, when the user swipes I am doing the following:

```
// Swipe right -> number - 1 (Previous page) 
// Swipe left -> number + 1 (Next page)
public void displayCardNumber(int number) {
    APIRequests apiRequests = new APIRequests();

    try {
        // Gets the JSONObject at 'number' and retrieves its img URL.
        JSONObject card = (JSONObject) cardsArray.get(number);
        String currentImageURL = (String) card.get("img");

        // Here is where my problem is.
        Bitmap bitmap = apiRequests.getImageBitmap(currentImageURL);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            setNewImage(bitmap);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

But `apiRequest.getImageBitmap(URL)` is where I have a problem.

I must download the image in order to display it, but not only does the following block of code not work when I download more than one image, I must also find an efficient way of displaying my cards (that requires background download perhaps?).

```
// Returns the image's bitmap using the URL
protected Bitmap getImageBitmap(String currentImageURL) {
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(currentImageURL).getContent());
        return bitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Why can't I download more than 1 image? Is my way of getting my `Bitmap` false?

Thank you.

Comment: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Glide      https://github.com/bumptech/glide .This is faster.

```
 Bitmap theBitmap = Glide.
    with(this).
    load(imgUrl). //image url as string
    asBitmap().
    into(100, 100). // Width and height
    get();
```

You can also use it with another way like this:

```
         Glide.with(context).load(url) // image url
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .placeholder(imgId) // If no image found the imgId is the default image id for the imageView
                .into(imageView); // imageView to show the image
```

Comment: Is there any way to give my picture a swipe effect with this library? It works so far, but when I swipe a card off, it disapears and it takes about 1 second for a new one to appear, I'd like to fill in this gap with an animation or something.

Comment: Yes you can add your custom animator object into thislibrary:
    Glide.with( context )
         .load( imgUrl)
         .animate( animation )  
         .into( imageView );
   
   //animation can be custom animator object or animation from your resource //

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution,

In order to load my image and display it I now use a library called [Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) that lets me do the following:

```
 // Load image, decode it to Bitmap and display Bitmap in ImageView
 ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
 ImageView i = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.cardDisplay);

 imageLoader.displayImage(currentImageURL, i);
```

I retrieve the correct URL in my `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground` and display it with the library's method.

Comment: I can accept my own answer in 2 days, I will be sure to do so.

Comment: This is a solution for your problem. Not an answer to your question. A bad idea to accept it.

Comment: Fair point, the library does handle my problem but I did not get to know exactly why I could not load 2 bitmaps.